# Css Animation not working in Google Chrome Flipclock

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations, css-transforms

my flipclock animation works well in Firefox & IE but doesn't work in Google Chrome.

HTML

```
<div id="tempFlipClock" data-position="LeftContent">
    <div id="FlipClockContainer" class="animated" data-dbitm='ClockContainer'>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="flip hoursPlay">
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <div class="up">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="down">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <div class="up">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="down">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="flip minutesPlay">
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <div class="up">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="down">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <div class="up">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="down">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="flip smallsize dnPlay">
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <div class="up">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="down">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <div class="up">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="down">
                            <div class="shadow"></div>
                            <div class="inn"></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clsServerDate">
                <span id="serverdate"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i put the fork here ... [PS]:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQxREV

it work on firefox but not chrome... in chrome only display white page.. this happend after the chrome update that disable flash..

Comment: its not even working on my *Firefox*.

Comment: the time not working because require date, actually that not what we looking for... the problem is ... if u test in chrome it will look white which mean problem... but in firefox it working fine.. because u can see the css there in black which mean correct @vivekkupadhyay

Comment: If I change your `ul.flip li a {
     height: 100%;
    -webkit-perspective: 200px;
    -moz-perspective: 200px;
    perspective: 200px;
}` to this `ul.flip li a {
     height: 100%; width: 100%; display: inline-block;
/*
    -webkit-perspective: 200px;
    -moz-perspective: 200px;
    perspective: 200px;
*/
}` then its working fine, for both the browsers.

Comment: mann u the best @vivekkupadhyay... Thanks so much! it WORK!!! CHARM!!! how you do it ? i would like to learn ...

Comment: u should put on answer post.. so i can credit u up

Comment: thanks @JohhnyNewbie :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `perspective` is the main culprit here. I've made changes in your *CSS* as:

**old CSS**:

```
ul.flip li a { 
   height: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 200px; 
  -moz-perspective: 200px; 
   perspective: 200px;
 }
```

**new CSS**:

```
ul.flip li a { 
   height: 100%; 
   width: 100%; 
   display: inline-block; 
   /* -webkit-perspective: 200px; 
      -moz-perspective: 200px; 
       perspective: 200px; */ 
   }
```

As you can see I've comment-out your `perspective` for `ul.flip li a` now its working fine for both **Chrome** as well as **FF**.

Hope it will do the trick for you :)

Comment: Last time it worked in both browser, after Chrome update 40.version i have problem with some my java and flash... i feel so lucky to have u here... thanks .. it does do the trick..